# Create user with uuid only and nested object array

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, prisma-graphql

With GraphQL, React and Prisma I am stuck creating a user with a uuid as id only and a nested object array that includes all input data related to that user. My goal is to show all input data relating to a user in React. How to create that user via mutation?

My code :

schema.graphql

```
type Query {
    info: String!
    feed: [Inputdata!]!
    user(id:ID!): User!
}
type Mutation {
  post(question: String!, answer: String!): Inputdata!
  createuser(id: String!): User!
}
type Inputdata {
  id: ID!
  question: String!
  answer: String!
  enteredById: String!
}
type User{
  id:ID!
  data: [Inputdata]
}
```

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    info: () => `This is the API of the Questionaire app`,
    feed: async (parent, args, context) => {
      return context.prisma.inputdata.findMany();
    },
    user: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      if(!args.id){
        throw new Error('id required')
      }
      return context.prisma.users.find(user => user.id === +args.id)
    }
  },
  User: {
    data(parent, args, context, info){
      //parent is the root object (User is the parent here)
      return context.prisma.data.filter(data => data.userid === parent.id)
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    post: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    let newInputData = context.prisma.inputdata.create({
        data: {
            question: args.question,
            answer: args.answer,
        },
    })
    return newInputData
    },
    createuser: (context) => {
      let newUser = context.prisma.users.create({
        data: {
          // need to fill with data? just want to create user-object with uuid
        }
      })
      return newUser
    }
  }
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: fs.readFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'),
        'utf8'
    ),
  resolvers,
  context: {
    prisma,
  }
})
server
  .listen()
  .then(({ url }) =>
    console.log(`Server is running on ${url}`)
  );
```

schema.prisma

```
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./dev.db"
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Inputdata {
  id          String   @unique
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  question    String
  answer      String
  enteredBy   User?    @relation(fields: [enteredById], references: [id])
  enteredById String?
}

model User {
  id          String      @id @unique
  Inputdata   Inputdata[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create the inputdata before the user? Then you'll have to create another mutation after creating the user to update the inputs with user id.

But it's better create the user in the input data mutation (if the user does not exist use `connectOrCreate`). Depends on your use case.

```
inputdata: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    let newInputData = context.prisma.inputdata.create({
        data: {
            question: args.question,
            answer: args.answer,
            enteredBy:{
              connectOrCreate:{
                 create:{
                   id:"uuid..."
                 },
                 where:{
                   id:"uuid..."
                 }
            }

        },
    })
    return newInputData
    }
```